# Asynchronous authentication angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

It's a little convoluted, but I'm using apache 2.4 as a webserver to host an angularjs 1.6 application and to reverse proxy into my nodejs backend. The apache webserver receives information about the user from another source, which I pass onto the backend. I've manage to secure the `/admin` page **IF** the user goes from `/`
 -> `/admin` but it doesn't work if the user directly accesses `/admin`. This is because I store information about the user when they visit `/`. When they view `/admin` directly, I think I'll have to make a request to the backend to see who it is (`GET /whois`), but I'm getting tripped up on how to resolve this as a promise. Is this even possible to achieve?

Here's a snippet of what I have that's working:

backend.js:

```
Class User{
    constructor(username,is_admin){
        this.username = username;
        this.is_admin = is_admin;
    }
}
app.get("/whois", function(req,res){
    const user = new User(req.username, req.is_admin);
    res.send(user);
});
```

frontend.js

```
services.factory("AS", function($q){
    return {
        auth_me : function(){
            //TODO: $http.get("/whois")
            let isAuthenticated = this.localStorage["is_admin"];
            if (isAuthenticated){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return $q.reject("unauthorized");
            }
        }
   }
}

myangApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/admin",{
        templateUrl : "pages/admin_page.html",
        resolve : {
            "auth" : function(AS){
                return AS.auth_me();
            }
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Use the `.then` method of the $http promise to return a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback` or `errorCallback`.

Comment: is that just a regular `$http.get("/whois").then(function(resp){`? I've tried that but it doesn't work, it will allow anyone access into the page

Comment: can you provide a pseudocode template? or link me to similar answers on stackoverflow?

Comment: See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).